# Bitlocker hanging encrypting drive

Tags: bitlocker

I am actually trying to remove bitlocker. But, whenever I try it tells me that bl cannot be removed until the encryption is completed. It is at 38.5% and has been.

So, I have tried everything I can think of... Trying to turn off bl on the drive. Removing, everything I have done leads me back to the same message. BL was active on the other three drives on this box, and it shut off there with no problems.

Now, the big question I just thought of.... This is in an external enclosure connected by a USB 3 port. If I put this drive in the computer, would it possibly continue? Has anyone seen USB cause a problem like this? Just a thought...

Comment: No; I would not attempt connect the drive through a SATA connection unless your willing to completely format the drive before hand.  At this point I wouldn’t disconnect the drive. Suspending the initial encryption process with a USB drive was likely a bad idea.

Comment: “Has anyone seen USB cause a problem like this? Just a thought...” This has nothing to do with USB. If you suddenly disconnect the drive while it is encrypting you will lose all of your data. At this point just let it grind through the encryption process and then, when it is finally done, you will be safe to remove encryption.